# How to calculate $f(n)=1\binom{n}{1}+2\binom{n}{2}+3\binom{n}{3}.....n\binom{n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics

$$f(n)=1\binom{n}{1}+2\binom{n}{2}+3\binom{n}{3}.....n\binom{n}{n}$$

Is there a formula for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2{n \choose k} = {(n+n^2)2^{n-2}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752298/prove-that-sum-k-0n-k2n-choose-k-nn22n-2)

Comment: @heropup This question has $k$, not $k^2$.

Comment: I am aware of that.  My solution describes how to solve both types, as well as how to recursively calculate the generalized form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to show that:
$$\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}.....+\binom{n}{n} = 2^n$$

Using this, try to find the derivative of: $(1 + x)^n$ and write out the binomial expansion. Set $x = 1$ and you'll get:

$$\binom{n}{1}+2\binom{n}{2}+3\binom{n}{3}.....n\binom{n}{n} = n*2^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = (1 + x)^n$, $S = f'(1) = n\cdot 2^{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Can you show that $k{n\choose k} =n{n-1\choose k-1}$?

Or use a counting argument: How many ways are there to pick a team from $n$ people, then pick a captain from the team?  If you pick the captain first, then half the time he won't be in the team, so it's only half of $n2^n$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: Expand $n(1+x)^{n-1}$ using the binomial theorem, then put $x=1$.