proofs of combinatoric summation series
I need to verify some results from Wolfram Alpha, either by citing references where these results are stated, or via proof. I found a reference for one that I need in Boros & Moll 2004: $\sum_{d=0}^k d\binom{k}{d} = 2^{k-1}k$.
The others are along similar lines. Eg:
$$\sum_{d=0}^k d(d-1)\binom{k}{d} = 2^{k-2}(k-1)k$$
I tried proof by induction but could not get the induction step to work out. How can I prove this property (or is there a reference that states this?)
(Disclaimers: not homework; I have a statistics background but last studied maths over 20 years ago).

See: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752298/302797

Thank you @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ - I was able to use the methods in that post for all of the expressions I had to verify. Very nifty!
